# ASP.NET Download Aspose PDF with embedded BMP

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspose.pdf

I need to render a BMP to a PDF using Aspose and download it.

The downloaded PDF is corrupt and Adobe will not open it.  The saved to file PDF is fine and opens.  Anyone know why the PDF from download is corrupted?

[image]

```
    protected void ASPxButton1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         WebsiteToImage websiteToImage = new WebsiteToImage(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, @"C:\Temp\Test.jpg");
        var generate = websiteToImage.Generate();
        // Create a MemoryStream object from image Byte array
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        websiteToImage.Bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        // create a PDF object
        Pdf pdf = new Pdf();
        // create a section and add it to pdf document
        Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Section MainSection = pdf.Sections.Add();
        //Add the radio form field to the paragraphs collection of the section
        // create an image object
        Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Image sample_image = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Image();
        // specify the image file path information
        //sample_image.ImageInfo.File = @"d:/pdftest/untitled.bmp";
        sample_image.ImageInfo.ImageStream = ms;
        // specify the image file type
        sample_image.ImageInfo.ImageFileType = Aspose.Pdf.Generator.ImageFileType.Bmp;
        // specify the image width information equal to page width 
        sample_image.ImageInfo.FixWidth = MainSection.PageInfo.PageWidth - MainSection.PageInfo.Margin.Left - MainSection.PageInfo.Margin.Right;
        // specify the image Height information equal to page Height
        sample_image.ImageInfo.FixWidth = MainSection.PageInfo.PageHeight - MainSection.PageInfo.Margin.Top - MainSection.PageInfo.Margin.Bottom;

        // create bitmap image object to load image information
        Bitmap myimage = websiteToImage.Bitmap;
        // check if the width of the image file is greater than Page width or not
        if (myimage.Width > MainSection.PageInfo.PageWidth)
            // if the Image width is greater than page width, then set the page orientation to Landscape
            MainSection.IsLandscape = true;
        else
            // if the Image width is less than page width, then set the page orientation to Portrait
            MainSection.IsLandscape = false;

        // add image to paragraphs collection of section
        MainSection.Paragraphs.Add(sample_image);
        // save the resultant PDF
        pdf.Save(@"C:\Temp\Test.pdf");
        pdf.Save(ms);
        byte[] bytes = ms.GetBuffer();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Operator.Emplid + "Gudiance.pdf");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        ms.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using a legacy Aspose.Pdf.generator approach, so in order to accomplish your requirements, we recommend you to please try using new Document Object Model of Aspose.Pdf namespace. Please try using following code snippet.

```
    // create a PDF object
Document pdf = new Document();
// create a section and add it to pdf document
Aspose.Pdf.Page MainSection = pdf.Pages.Add();
//Add the radio form field to the paragraphs collection of the section
// create an image object
Aspose.Pdf.Image sample_image = new Aspose.Pdf.Image();
// specify the image file path information
sample_image.File = @"C:\pdftest\OutOfMemoryDemo\OutOfMemoryDemo\Sample.bmp";
// specify the image width information equal to page width 
sample_image.FixWidth = MainSection.PageInfo.Width - MainSection.PageInfo.Margin.Left - MainSection.PageInfo.Margin.Right;
// specify the image Height information equal to page Height
sample_image.FixWidth = MainSection.PageInfo.Height - MainSection.PageInfo.Margin.Top - MainSection.PageInfo.Margin.Bottom;

// create bitmap image object to load image information
System.Drawing.Bitmap myimage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(@"C:\pdftest\OutOfMemoryDemo\OutOfMemoryDemo\Sample.bmp");
// check if the width of the image file is greater than Page width or not
if (myimage.Width > MainSection.PageInfo.Width)
    // if the Image width is greater than page width, then set the page orientation to Landscape
    MainSection.PageInfo.IsLandscape = true;
else
    // if the Image width is less than page width, then set the page orientation to Portrait
    MainSection.PageInfo.IsLandscape = false;

// add image to paragraphs collection of section
MainSection.Paragraphs.Add(sample_image);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

// save the resultant PDF
pdf.Save(stream);

StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream); 
String Data = reader.ReadToEnd();
this.Title = Data;
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
Response.AddHeader("Accept-Header", stream.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", stream.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0″");
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "cache");
Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "private");
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("inline;filename={0}", "article" + "docId"+ ".pdf"));
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

*PS, My name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.*